# iPhone/iOS App runs fine, but if I force quit by deleting it from the running programs crashes on next start

Tags: iphone, freeze

Ok, I'm confused..

I have an app that if I launch and use runs fine.. However if I click on the home button pausing the app, and then go into the list of running apps by double clicking the home button, and then delete the app instance in that list, effectively killing/ending that app run, and go back and click on the icon to launch the app fresh, the app simply hangs with a blank black screen... every time I try to start the app after that first time I get this problem.

Is there some event I need to handle in my app, to make sure it cleans itself up properly for relaunch?

I am admittedly confused and would appreciate any help.

Comment: actually it doesn't appear to crash, it just flat out hangs.

Comment: are u running the app on device or simulator ?

Comment: Are u using any resources in your apps like files saved in phone or using plist or images. And if you are try to edit that files and in between you are closing your app...then again restarting your app will be in unstable state as the Resources are not properly handle....

This could be one case either..when using external resources..

Comment: @Hadi, The behavior is the same on a physical device AND the simulator.  It also completely CRASHES the iPad simulator when I do this behavior.

Comment: @Dhiren I am using images, and do have a SQLITE DB as well. But I am not editing any of them, all my accesses are read only, with the sole exception of a copy that happens at app launch to move my SQL DB into place, if it isn't already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same weird problem, then i have realized that this only happens if you run the application through the XCODE (Debug Mode).
The application locks because the debugger/xcode receives the SIGNKILL and locks the application so you can inspect the code.

If you run the application directly from the device the application gets killed and does not remain locked on the screen :)

Even one year later, i had the same problem, so hope that helps someone that has the same problem.